# Hibernate : java.lang.ClassCastException on save

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having a strange problem with HIBERNATE today, it gives me  `java.lang.ClassCastException` when i try to save an object to database.

Here is the stack trace of the error :

```
15:57:24,307 DEBUG AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource:106 - Adding transactional method 'createNombreConnexion' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
15:57:24,307 DEBUG AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource:106 - Adding transactional method 'save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
15:57:24,682 ERROR stderr:71 - java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to ma.dataprotect.sensipro.model.NombreConnexion

15:57:24,687 ERROR stderr:71 -  at ma.dataprotect.sensipro.dao.impl.NombreConnexionDaoImpl.save(NombreConnexionDaoImpl.java:30)

15:57:24,687 ERROR stderr:71 -  at ma.dataprotect.sensipro.dao.impl.NombreConnexionDaoImpl.save(NombreConnexionDaoImpl.java:1)

15:57:24,687 ERROR stderr:71 -  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

15:57:24,687 ERROR stderr:71 -  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

15:57:24,692 ERROR stderr:71 -  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

15:57:24,692 ERROR stderr:71 -  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

15:57:24,692 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)

15:57:24,692 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)

15:57:24,697 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)

15:57:24,697 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)

15:57:24,697 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

15:57:24,697 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)

15:57:24,702 ERROR stderr:71 -  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy407.save(Unknown Source)

15:57:24,702 ERROR stderr:71 -  at ma.dataprotect.sensipro.services.impl.NombreConnexionServiceImpl.createNombreConnexion(NombreConnexionServiceImpl.java:28)

15:57:24,702 ERROR stderr:71 -  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

15:57:24,702 ERROR stderr:71 -  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

15:57:24,707 ERROR stderr:71 -  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

15:57:24,707 ERROR stderr:71 -  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

15:57:24,707 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)

15:57:24,707 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)

15:57:24,712 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)

15:57:24,712 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)

15:57:24,712 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

15:57:24,712 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)

15:57:24,712 ERROR stderr:71 -  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy410.createNombreConnexion(Unknown Source)

15:57:24,712 ERROR stderr:71 -  at ma.dataprotect.sensipro.util.LoginBean.login(LoginBean.java:85)

15:57:24,712 ERROR stderr:71 -  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

15:57:24,712 ERROR stderr:71 -  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

15:57:24,717 ERROR stderr:71 -  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

15:57:24,717 ERROR stderr:71 -  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

15:57:24,717 ERROR stderr:71 -  at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)

15:57:24,717 ERROR stderr:71 -  at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)

15:57:24,717 ERROR stderr:71 -  at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)

15:57:24,717 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)

15:57:24,717 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)

15:57:24,722 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)

15:57:24,722 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)

15:57:24,722 ERROR stderr:71 -  at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)

15:57:24,722 ERROR stderr:71 -  at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)

15:57:24,722 ERROR stderr:71 -  at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)

15:57:24,722 ERROR stderr:71 -  at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)

15:57:24,722 ERROR stderr:71 -  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)

15:57:24,722 ERROR stderr:71 -  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)

15:57:24,722 ERROR stderr:71 -  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)

15:57:24,727 ERROR stderr:71 -  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)

15:57:24,727 ERROR stderr:71 -  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)

15:57:24,727 ERROR stderr:71 -  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)

15:57:24,727 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

15:57:24,727 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)

15:57:24,727 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)

15:57:24,727 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)

15:57:24,727 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

15:57:24,732 ERROR stderr:71 -  at ma.dataprotect.sensipro.util.FiltreUTF8.doFilter(FiltreUTF8.java:48)

15:57:24,732 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)

15:57:24,732 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

15:57:24,732 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

15:57:24,732 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)

15:57:24,732 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)

15:57:24,732 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,737 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)

15:57:24,737 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,737 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)

15:57:24,737 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,737 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)

15:57:24,737 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,737 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)

15:57:24,737 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,742 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:57:24,747 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)

15:57:24,752 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)

15:57:24,757 ERROR stderr:71 -  at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)

15:57:24,757 ERROR stderr:71 -  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

15:57:24,757 ERROR stderr:71 -  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

15:57:24,757 ERROR stderr:71 -  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the entity with the problem :

```
package ma.dataprotect.sensipro.model;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "nombre_connexion")
public class NombreConnexion implements java.io.Serializable{

    private Long id;
    private Organism organism;
    private Date dateConnexion;
    private Long nombreConn;

    public NombreConnexion() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public NombreConnexion(Organism organism, Date dateConnexion,
            Long nombreConnexion) {
        super();
        this.organism = organism;
        this.dateConnexion = dateConnexion;
        this.nombreConn= nombreConnexion;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_organism", nullable = false)
    public Organism getOrganism() {
        return organism;
    }

    public void setOrganism(Organism organism) {
        this.organism = organism;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date_connexion", unique=true, nullable = false)
    public Date getDateConnexion() {
        return dateConnexion;
    }

    public void setDateConnexion(Date dateConnexion) {
        this.dateConnexion = dateConnexion;
    }

    @Column(name = "nombre_connexion", nullable = false)
    public Long getNombreConn() {
        return nombreConn;
    }

    public void setNombreConn(Long nombreConn) {
        this.nombreConn = nombreConn;
    }
}
```

The Generic save method :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T save(T t) {
        return (T) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(t);
    }
```

the code that generates the probleme :

```
nombreConnexion = new NombreConnexion();
                                        nombreConnexion.setOrganism(user.getOrganism());
nombreConnexion.setDateConnexion(new Date());
nombreConnexion.setNombreConn((long) 1);
System.out.println(nombreConnexion);
                                        nombreConnexionService.createNombreConnexion(nombreConnexion);
```

**EDITED** : code of nombreConnexionServiceImpl.createNombreConnexion(nombreConnexion) [Nothing Important !]

```
public void createNombreConnexion(NombreConnexion nombreConnexion) {

    nombreConnexionDao.save(nombreConnexion);

}
```

**EDITED 2 ( I hope this will help ):** i changed the type of id to Integer now the error is :

```
16:30:46,818 ERROR stderr:71 - java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to ma.dataprotect.sensipro.model.NombreConnexion
```

We are using spring and hibernate, all was working fine i don't understand what could be the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Serializable object returned by the Hibernate session's save() method is the ID ("the generated identifier") of the object, not the object itself. So it's the cast to (T) in the save method that fails. Either change the return type or return the saved object instead.

Comment: please notice the `System.out.println(nombreConnexion);` before the service class above it gives  `ma.dataprotect.sensipro.model.NombreConnexion@128f29b` which states clearly that the object is not **Long**, i don't know why is it reacting like that !!!

Comment: Even so, you have not shown us code from inside the service class's createNombreConnexion(..) method. Could you show the relevant bits? Or is nombreConnexion object really just being passed through without any modification? 

Or maybe simply add another System.out.println in the save method. Just to be absolutely sure the expected object arrives there.

Comment: I see. I was hoping for more ;) Still, that ClassCastException is originating in the save(..) method so there MUST be a problem with the object there. Please do another System.out.println(t) there (or connect a debugger to have a look).

Comment: Actually, make that 2 System.out.printlns: one for variable t and one for the return value of getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(t); before casting it to T.

Comment: Yeah, silly me. It's the return value. Hibernate gives you the ID there, not the object you just saved. Updating my answer to reflect this...